# Nokogiri replace arbitrary nodes

Tags: ruby, xpath, replace, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrape some piece of legislation. Here's an excerpt of the code:

```
<h5>
<span class="expanderComparator clickable">&nbsp;</span>
<span class="context-menu">&nbsp;</span>
<a href="index.html#a340">
<strong>Art. 340</strong>
</a>
<sup>
<a href="#fn-#a340-1">1</a>
</sup>
<a href="index.html#a340">Mesures conservatoires</a>
</h5>
```

This piece of code is repeated for each article (can be above a thousand), but its structure follows essentially the same pattern.

I'm trying to build an array as such:

```
a340 = { 'number' => '340', 'title' => 'Mesures conservatoires'}
```

So obviously I looked at Nokogiri, which seems to be appropriate. Here are the problems though:

- this piece `<sup><a href="#fn-#a340-1">1</a></sup>` needs to be replaced by a space (" ") => `h1 = @doc.at_xpath "//sup/a" h1.content = " "`
- all `span` and `a` tags need to be removed
- ultimately, keep only what's inside the `h5` tag (because there's other bloat as well that's not required) => `.css("h5").text`

I was essentially able to reach all of the above, yet somehow I'm unable to chain them up into one logical software.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Caveat: it needs to be pure ruby only, so no rails :(

Comment: What's the resource trying to be scraped?, to see if there's a pattern, and when you say you want to build an array, that's a hash, or do you want to create an array of hashes?, also, as the number is 340, and the object a340, is the name also variable?

Comment: Here's a link to the source: https://www.admin.ch/opc/fr/classified-compilation/20061121/index.html I'm indeed aiming at an array of hashes, specifically an array or articles. The name of the object is also a variable (ie its an iteration of one article)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe accessing to `'#lawcontent .collapseable h5'` could work:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = 'https://www.admin.ch/opc/fr/classified-compilation/20061121/index.html'
doc = Nokogiri.HTML(open url)
articles_hash = doc.css('#lawcontent .collapseable h5').map do |element|
  {
    'number' => element.css('a strong').text.sub(/\AArt. /, ''),
    'title'  => element.css('a:last-child').text.sub(/\AArt. \d+ |\A\d+/, '')
  }
end
puts articles_hash

# [
#  {"number"=>"1", "title"=>"Objet"}, 
#  {"number"=>"2", "title"=>"Causes de nature internationale"},
#  {"number"=>"3", "title"=>"Organisation des tribunaux et des autorit\u00E9s de conciliation"},
#  ...
# ]
```

This iterates and gets until the article #407.

Comment: Having all the data within the array, do you really need them as variables?